# c++ move argument signature not propagated

Tags: c++, c++11, parameter-passing, move-semantics, rvalue-reference

`map` is an `std::unordered_map`. `T` has a move constructor.

```
void foo(const std::string& s, T&& t) {
    map.insert(std::pair<std::string, T>(s, t));
}

T t;
foo("", std::move(t));
```

---

Why isn't this code calling `template<class U, class V> std::pair(U&& a, V&& b)`?

---

Why do we need to use `std::move(t)` to get the right behavior?

```
void foo(const std::string& s, T&& t) {
    map.insert(std::pair<std::string, T>(s, std::move(t)));
}
```

Comment: That's because `t` is an lvalue (of type `T&&`, which simply means it will match an rvalue argument, not that `t` is itself an rvalue), not an rvalue. The `std::move` is to make it an rvalue.

Comment: [This article](http://thbecker.net/articles/rvalue_references/section_01.html) does a good job of explaining rvalue references

Comment: The code *does* call `insert(V&&v)` because the `std::pair` is a prvalue.  However it does not move out of `t`.

Comment: @M.M you're right I wanted to say about pair constructor. I fixed it.